# Nvidia display settings are not available

Tags: graphics-card, display

I just built a computer and installed the Gigabyte GTX 1660 Super. I connected my MSI Optix Mag271CQR monitor with HDMI and I get a pop up saying 
“NVIDIDA Display settings are not available. You are not currently using a display attached to an NVIDIA GPU”

I can see it says running in the settings. I have, stopped, started again, uninstalled, reinstalled and am at a loss as to why it’s not responding.
I have tried all things I’ve found on other forums and YouTube to no avail.
I have downloaded all the drivers from NVIDIA GForce Experience too.
There is a DP cable that came with the monitor but when I use that, I get nothing.
The HDMI lights up the monitor and shows my windows screen but I can’t access the Nvidia control panel and keep getting this message.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. It was a silly mistake by me.
I plugged it into the hdmi socket without noticing the ones down below which were do ones and attached to the graphics card. Those little rubber covers fooled me.
Anyway, all good. Thanks